# How to crop the detected object after training using YOLO?

Tags: yolo, darknet

I am using YOLO for model training. I want to crop the detected object.
For Darknet repository am using is: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/

For Detection and storing output coordinates in a text file am using this:
!./darknet detector test data_for_colab/obj.data data_for_colab/yolov3-tiny-obj.cfg yolov3-tiny-obj_10000.weights -dont_show -ext_output < TEST.txt > result.txt
[Result.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZosZ.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering in the TEST.txt file you have details as the sample image.
You can use **re** module of python for text pattern detection, ie your "class_name".

## Parsing the .txt file

```
import re
path='/content/darknet/result.txt'
myfile=open(path,'r')
lines=myfile.readlines()
pattern= "class_name"

for line in lines:
  if re.search(pattern,line):
    Cord_Raw=line
Cord=Cord_Raw.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].split("  ")
```

Now we will get the coordinates in a list.

## Coordinate calculation

```
x_min=int(Cord[1])
x_max=x_min + int(Cord[5])
y_min=int(Cord[3])
y_max=y_min+ int(Cord[7])
```

## Cropping from the actual image

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("Image.jpg")
crop_img = img[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]
cv2.imwrite("Object.jpg",crop_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yolov5 you can easily crop detected object:

```
    python detect.py --save-crop --source folderpath --weight yolov5s.pt
```

To crop specific class add --classes x  (x is class index number)

```
   python detect.py --save-crop --classes 0 --source folderpath --weight yolov5s.pt
```

It crops only person detected an image (person has class index 0 in cocodataset)